# How to add an animated svg via javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

```
<svg width="5cm" height="3cm"  viewBox="0 0 500 300">
<path id="path1" d="M100,250 C 100,50 400,50 400,250"
    fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="7.06"  />
<circle r="17.64" fill="red">
<animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="1" rotate="auto" >
   <mpath xlink:href="#path1"/>
</animateMotion>
</circle>
</svg>
```

If I write the svg in plain html/svg file, it works fine, the circle animates correctly.
But if I add the circle element dynamically via javascript, circle was added, but it didn't animate. What's wrong? js code:

```
    var svg = $("svg"); //use jquery
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle");
circle.setAttribute("r", "5");
circle.setAttribute("fill", "red");
var ani = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","animateMotion");
ani.setAttribute("dur", "26s");
ani.setAttribute("repeatCount", "indefinite");
ani.setAttribute("rotate", "auto");
var mpath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","mpath");
mpath.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#path1");
ani.appendChild(mpath);
circle.appendChild(ani);
svg.append(circle);
```

Comment: Can you post the full HTML file instead of that snippet? I don't know what JS framework you're using to select the SVG. And it would be nice to know if you're putting SVG markup inline or embedding it with an embed tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `setAttributeNS` on "mpath" instead of `setAttribute`.

```
mpath.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "#path1");
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zh553/

Comment: thanks a lot, it works! As you say, i used 'setAttribute' method wrongly to 'mpath'

Comment: @dencey no problem, it was an interesting question :)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with using `setAttributeNS` on "mpath" instead of `setAttribute`.

However at least for Chrome (and other WebKit based browsers?) it seems to be necessary to pay attention to http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-ElSetAttrNS where it says the second parameter is the qualifiedName, the qualified name of the attribute to create or alter.

```
mpath.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "#path1");
```

Or, if needed, more generically:

```
mpath.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
                     mpath.lookupPrefix("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink") + ":href",
                     "#path1");
```

Also discussed at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22958